# How do I execute several substitutions on the contents of every file within several directories?

Tags: perl, file-io, substitution

I need to carry out several substitutions on the *contents* of files in different directories (not recursively).

For example, for all files in dir */foo/bar*:

```
s/blue/red/;
s/green/yellow/;
```

And for all files in dir */foobar/bar*:

```
s/orange/black/;
```

What is the most efficient way of writing this script?

My substitution scripts are all one-liners at the moment, and so I'm pretty much in the dark about how to integrate them in a full script cleanly.

---

I have included a snippet from my non-functional test script below, if it's of any use.

```
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Cannot open directory: $!\n";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

foreach(@files) {
    my $filename = $_;   
    open(FILE, $filename);

    while (my $data = <FILE>) {
        # Substitution lines
        }
    close(FILE);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try to solve the problem using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -i".bak" -n -e 's/blue/glue/g; print;' *
```

You could use many -e, or alternatively use many s///. This also backs up current files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @fallenland Thank you for your answer, but I already have my substitutions in several one-liners. I am trying to combine them into a single script which will chdir and execute them to several directories. Apologies if my question was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the code to match what you want, you're going to have to use a module
that parses command line args like Getopt::Long; I'm not sure of the syntax, but you'll need something that allows you do do arrays of strings on both ends; i'm sure there's a better way to process args to that lets you read them in as a key, value map.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# invoke with:
# script.pl <name part to match> <name part to replace> <directory to examine> <directory to examine...>
use Getopt::Long;
my %opts = ();

... read in match keys / values ...

my $dir = shift;
while(-d $dir){
    @files_in_dir = <$dir/*>;
    foreach my $file (@files_in_dir){
        my @lines = ();
        open(my $IN, '<', $dir/$file);
        while(<$IN>){
            foreach $i (1..#@$opt{match}){
                if(/@{$opt{match}}[$i]/){
                    s/@{$opt{match}}[$i]/@{$opt{replace}}[$i]/;
                }  
            }
            push @lines, $_;
        }
        close $IN;
        open(my $OUT, '>', $dir/$file);
        print $OUT "$_" foreach(@lines);
        close $OUT;
    }
    $dir = shift;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory traversal is probably the big bottleneck, so you should try to do that only once.

```
find . -type f -exec perl -i".bak" -pe '
  if($ARGV =~ m%^./foo/bar/%){s/blue/red/g;s/green/yellow/g;}
  s/orange/black/ if($ARGV =~ m%^./foobar/bar/%' {} \;
```